# Finding $A^2 = 0$ with $A\neq 0$, A is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to make an equation:

$$AA = 0 \Leftrightarrow A = 0A^{-1} \Leftrightarrow A = 0$$

which is odd because... since $A$ is not meant to be the null matrix then it could be invertible, which could make this equation possible, but the result makes this equation impossible by giving $A = 0$.

Did I make a mistake or is this just some weird quirk of matrices?

Comment: Here is a counterexample: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: If $AA = 0$ then $A$ is singular and an inverse does not exist.

Comment: @Silence. Google nilpotent matrices.

Comment: Just $A \ne 0$ doesn't mean that $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are working with $n \times n$ matrices, then the ring $\text{Mat}_R(n)$ of $n \times n$ matrices over a ring $R$ is not an integer domain.

So it is not true that $AA = 0 \Leftrightarrow A = 0$.